# Does the compensated law of demand hold for giffen good?

Tags: microeconomics, demand, giffen-goods

Considering 2 goods good 1 and good 2 where good 1 is given. Can you show me with a help of a diagram when the price of good 1 aka the giffen good increases?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: But this was what was exactly asked in my test. I am kinda sure that the question is well framed.